# Power circuit for 3 AA batteries for ATtiny85

Tags: batteries, remote-control, attiny85

I'm using an ATtiny85 and 3 AA batteries in series to create a DIY remote control. Does anyone know what kind of circuit I need to safely and correctly use the batteries? I assume it'll need some smoothing caps and maybe a diode, but I'm not experience enough to come up with it on my own. Can anyone help?

Comment: Depends, what's connected downstream? Just the ATtiny?

Comment: What kind of batteries, and what do you mean safely? What would the diode do? Do you need to consider if batteries are inserted with wrong polarity? Are they rechargeable or not? Chemistry?

Comment: @winny It's the ATtiny, a push button, an LED, and a radio module I got off Amazon.

Comment: @Justme They're going to be regular AA alkaline batteries. I'm not going to be the one using it, so I need to consider reverse polarity and other possible mistakes. They are not rechargeable. The reason I'm asking because of my knowledge of power sources, a lot of them need some caps to smooth the signal because many power sources aren't consistent, or reverse polarity diodes from electrical discharge or something of the sort.

Comment: OK, so since you are not the user, someone might change to rechargeable batteries without you knowing, so you should still make it safe with rechargeables. But now you have some RF module, what voltages it works with - it may change everything. Add that piece of important knowledge that it's not only the Tiny85 you need to power.

Comment: @Justme the RF module is also 5V, I made sure it could be powered by the tiny

Comment: @Justme also how do I need to make the circuit for it to be safe with rechargeable batteries?

Comment: Are you sure the RF module is 5V? Itf it is, you'll need a step up regulator as 3x1.5V is 4.5V. Do you have a part number for it?